# css - why my text box is not showing up?

Tags: css, html, alignment

On [my website](http://goo.gl/ygSXK), section "Presse and Medias", I'd like a white square to appear a few px next to the video (on the right side) with the word "hello" in it.
Unfortunately this is not working. I see the word hello, but not in a white square.
Any idea what the issue is and how to fix it?
Many thanks,

Here is my html:

```
<div class="section" id="medias">
<div class="center">
     <iframe width="350" height="200" class="youtube-player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qqXi8WmQ_WM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="medias-txt"
        <p>hello</p></div>
 </div>
</div><!--END page4-->
```

And here is my css:

```
#medias-txt
{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: have you tried relative positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't closing your div tag

```
<div class="section" id="medias">
<div class="center">
     <iframe width="350" height="200" class="youtube-player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qqXi8WmQ_WM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="medias-txt">
        <p>hello</p></div>
 </div>
</div><!--END page4-->
```

This should do the trick.

PS Love the video on that page :)

Comment: Good spot! Thanks ;)
That said I have closed the div tag but still don't see the white square... (have uploaded a new version with the tag closed). Any idea?

Comment: I think I've got it. I had a look at your styles.css style sheet in firebug and you have a couple of blank spaces before #medias-txt. I removed these in firebug and the style kicked in. I'm not sure why this was causing an issue though. Maybe some erroneous character. I had a look at the source of the stylesheet directly and it doesn't seem to appear there. Try deleting  any spacing between #medias-txt and the end of the youtube-player style declaration and see if that works

Comment: Gosh.. This is making me crazy... I have now removed the extra blank spaces (also changed the size of the video) and now (1) the white square is still invisible, (2) the white frame around the video disappeared and (3) the "hello" text is now under the video... Grrrrr...

Answer (score -1):

In your css, you need to add spaces between the colons and the content. 
eg:

```
#medias-txt
{
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: In CSS whitespace make no difference.